# Converting this pytorch network in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have this network:

(ngf = 160, nc=3,nz=100)

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(  # non usa il dense ma noise Size([16, 100, 1, 1]) che crea sotto
            # input is Z, going into a convolution
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(nz, ngf * 16, 4, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 16),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*16) x 4 x 4
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 16, ngf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*8) x 8 x 8
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*4) x 16 x 16
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*2) x 32 x 32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf) x 64 x 64
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
            # state size. (nc) x 128 x 128
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)
```

and I would like to convert it into tensorflow 2.0. So far this was my attempt:

(ngf = 160, nc=3,nz=100)

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    N = 4 
    model.add(layers.Input((100,1,1)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(nz, (4, 4), padding='same',use_bias=False))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.ReLU())
    #assert model.output_shape == (None, N, N, ngf*16)

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(ngf*16, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.ReLU())
   # model.add(layers.Reshape((N*2, N*2, ngf*8)))
   # assert model.output_shape == (None, N*2, N*2, ngf*8)

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(ngf*8, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.ReLU())
  #  model.add(layers.Reshape((N*4, N*4, ngf*4)))
   # assert model.output_shape == (None, N*4, N*4, ngf*4) 

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(ngf*4, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.ReLU())
   # model.add(layers.Reshape((N*8, N*8, ngf*2)))
   # assert model.output_shape == (None, N*8, N*8, ngf*2) 

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(ngf*2, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.ReLU())
    #model.add(layers.Reshape((N*16, N*16, ngf)))
   # assert model.output_shape == (None, N*16, N*16, ngf) 

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
   # model.add(layers.Reshape((N*32, N*32, nc)))
  #  assert model.output_shape == (None, N*32, N*32, nc) 

    return model
```

But sadly this is not working. So far the problem is that the shapes are not correct,and for sure the error has to be on the feeding of the input to the conv2d(that's my guess,at least). The main thing that is giving me trouble is that in pytorch I can specify the output dimension from a conv2dTranspose while I can't in tensorflow. There has to be something that I'm missing. I also thought that maybe I could have added a dense layer and then apply a reshape layer before the first conv2dtranspose,but am I changing the shape of the network/am I icnreasing the number of parameters? I had such doubt so I avoided to do such things.

Comment: Have you solved your issues?
tensorflows Conv2DTranspose first argument "filters" is "the dimensionality of the output space (i.e. the number of output filters in the convolution".
And are you sure layers.BatchNormalization() and torchs nn.BatchNorm2d() behave equivalent?